# How do I get rid of NullPointerException in Processing?

Tags: arduino, processing

I have connected my arduino code serially to processing. I get a run time error that says NullPointerException in Processing.

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
String val ;
int[] colour_val  ;


void setup(){

   size(500,500);
   String portName = Serial.list()[0];
   myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw(){
   if (myPort.available() >0){

      val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
   }
   if (val != null){
      append(colour_val,val);
      for ( float v : colour_val)
         background(v);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this variable:

```java
int[] colour_val;
```

You don't give it a value, so by default it's nothing, or a `null` value.

Now look at this line:

```java
append(colour_val, val);
```

You're passing `null` into the `append()` function. You might expect that to add the value so you have a single-index array, but that's not how it works. You can't pass `null` into this function, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

To fix the problem, just initialize the `colour_val` variable to an empty array instead of `null`:

```java
int[] colour_val  = new int[0];
```

But even after you fix that, you have another problem. The `append()` function doesn't actually change the array you pass into it. Instead, it creates a new array and returns that. You have to store this new array into a variable. You could store it back in the same variable:

```java
colour_val = append(colour_val,val);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html).

This isn't really related to your problem, but look at this section of code:

```java
for ( float v : colour_val)
     background(v);
```

This doesn't really make a lot of sense. Let's say you have 3 values in your `colour_val` array: 0, 128, and 255. This loop is like calling the `background()` function 3 times in a row:

```java
background(0);
background(128);
background(255);
```

But notice that the first two calls to `background()` don't really do anything, since you immediately draw over them with the last call to the `background()` function. The user will only ever see that last call to `background()`, so you really don't need this loop.